# How to decode HTML encoded text in MS Access

Tags: html, ms-access, encoding, url-encoding

I have a table field in MS Access 2003 which contains HTML encoded strings like this:

```
&#913;&#957;&#964;&#945;&#947;&#969;&#957;&#953;&#963;&#956;&#972;&#962; &#960;&#945;&#947;&#954;&#959;&#963;&#956;&#943;&#959;&#965; &#949;&#960;&#953;&#960;&#941;&#948;&#959;&#965; &#963;&#964;&#951;&#957; &#954;&#945;&#964;&#940;&#961;&#964;&#953;&#963
```

How can I decode this into a "normal string", using MS Access?

Thanks in advance.

---

Here what I have so far. Using the Vb code provided [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1512) (BTW I could open that page only from IE7, not from FF 3.5 nor Chrome 2), I wrote following function:

```
Private Function UnicodeDecode(StringToDecode As String) As String
  Dim TempAns As String
  Dim CurChr As Integer
  CurChr = 1
  Do Until CurChr - 1 = Len(StringToDecode)
    Select Case Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr, 2)
    Case "&#"
      TempAns = TempAns & Chr(Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr + 2, 3))
       CurChr = CurChr + 5
    Case Else
      TempAns = TempAns & Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr, 1)
    End Select
    CurChr = CurChr + 1
  Loop
  UnicodeDecode = TempAns
End Function
```

Now, this works when you provide decimal value of the character up to 255. If I try to execute, for example:

```
Chr(338)
```

it fails with "Invalid procedure call or argument". I suppose MS Access supports only ISOlat1 standard by default, according to [this reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). However, I need to convert unicode characters with decimal values above 913, which is ISOgrk3.

Does anybody knows how can I achieve that?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use msxml6.dll (Microsoft XML v6.0) to convert html entities to plain text in VBA:

```
Set oDOMDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Html = "&lt;Black&gt;&quot;2"
oDOMDoc.LoadXML ("<root>" & Html & "</root>")
HtmlDecode = oDOMDoc.Text
```

Comment: Alas, this doesn't seem to work. For me, at least.

As soon as you add &eacute; to the HTML string, it returns an empty string. (VBA Office 2013, Dutch).

Comment: The same goes for me with mentioned &eacute; and many other strings from ISO Latin Alphabet No. 1 table, for example &lsquo; so this method is unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks so much. 
I have to change some code if input array have **4** digit (like persian)
also the function should be **public** when you want to use it as macro in MS Access.
apply **ChrW()** instead of Chr().

```
Public Function UnicodeDecode(StringToDecode As String) As String
  Dim TempAns As String
  Dim CurChr As Integer
  CurChr = 1
  Do Until CurChr - 1 = Len(StringToDecode)
    Select Case Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr, 2)
    Case "&#"
      TempAns = TempAns & ChrW(Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr + 2, 4))
       CurChr = CurChr + 6
    Case Else
      TempAns = TempAns & Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr, 1)
    End Select
    CurChr = CurChr + 1
  Loop
  UnicodeDecode = TempAns
End Function
```

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work so I revised it to change your DO UNTIL to "Do Until CurChr > Len(StringToDecode)" and your ChrW(Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr + 2, 4))  to "ChrW(Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr + 2, 3))". The former is because the loop wasn't terminating and was ending up with an overflow (you might consider changing CurChr to Long, since you're limiting the length of the string you can decode to the maximum value for a VBA integer, which is only 32K-odd characters). The latter change is because you were passing the ";" along with the number.

Comment: Also, it seems to me you ought not be assuming the encoded characters are going to be 3 digits, and instead pull out the value between "&#" and ";", since unicode characters can have numbers up to 64K-odd. Also, unicode characters can be encoded as decimal or Hex, so for full compatibility, you'd need to account for Hex values, as well. For pulling out the values, you might try use Split() with the ";" character as your delimiter and then process the resulting array.

Comment: Bang on with the chrW()

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article that suggests a number of directions you might go in:

[Using Unicode in Visual Basic 6](http://www.cyberactivex.com/UnicodeTutorialVb.htm) (Access's VBA is an superset of VB6)

Then you'll probably want to muck around with these Access/VBA functions:

- StrConv()
- AscB()
- ChrB()

That doesn't resolve all of it, but that should give you a starting point.

Note for StrConv() the two constants for the 2nd argument, vbUnicode and vbFromUnicode, and the last, optional argument is the character set, which for Greek is given in the URL cited above as 161 (there doesn't seem to be a named constant for this -- the dbLangGreek constant returns ";LANGID=0x0408;CP=1253;COUNTRY=0").

It occurs to me that as long as you're limited to Greek for this, you might need to just set up an array that maps the characters to their corresponding numeric encoding. But I think it would be better to use a solution that handles more than one encoding.

Last of all, you might try going to this page on Michael Kaplan's old website, Trigeminal.com:

[The Localized Website of Trigeminal Software, Inc.](http://trigeminal.com/website.asp?1033)

...and scroll down to the end, "Miscellaneous I18n resources on this site." Much of that information is out of date for .NET and other programming, but it's still going to apply to VB6/Access VBA.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, that is a lot of resources, I'll check them out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but always looking for a better mousetrap...

```
Public Function HtmlDecode(StringToDecode As Variant) As String
    Set oMSHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set e = oMSHTML.createElement("T")
    e.innerHTML = StringToDecode
    HtmlDecode = e.innerText
End Function
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you add some explanations or comments (what is `"T"`?), and `Dim` your variables so it runs with `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this post to decode 'html encoded xml' that's embedded in an xml element.
The currently accepted answer of @David-W-Fenton is about url decoding which does not solve the question nor my problem.
The answer of @Ruslan has a problem when html entities are thrown into the mix (as mentioned by @Roemer).
Here I have a working example with unicode control codes and html entities, which solves these problems and (im)proves the answer given by @Tx-Barnstormer:

```
Public Sub TestDecoding()
    Dim htmlEncoded As String
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    
    htmlEncoded = "&lt;tests&gt;" & _
        "&lt;eacute&gt;&eacute;&lt;/eacute&gt;" & _
        "&lt;amp&gt;&amp;amp;&lt;/amp&gt;" & _
        "&lt;childNode&gt;&lt;childNode attribute=&quot;testvalue&quot;&gt;I&apos;m a childNode&lt;/childNode&gt;&lt;/childNode&gt;" & _
        "&lt;otrema&gt;&#xF6;&lt;/otrema&gt;" & _
        "&lt;hyphen&gt;&#x2013;&lt;/hyphen&gt;" & _
    "&lt;/tests&gt;"
    
    Debug.Print HtmlDecode(htmlEncoded)
End Sub

Function HtmlDecode(str As String) As String
    Dim dom As Object

    Set dom = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    dom.Open
    dom.Write str
    dom.Close
    HtmlDecode = dom.Body.innerText
End Function
```

The formatted output of TestDecode:

```
<tests>
    <eacute>é</eacute>
    <amp>&amp;</amp>
    <childNode><childNode attribute="testvalue">I'm a childNode</childNode></childNode>
    <otrema>ö</otrema>
    <hyphen>–</hyphen>
</tests>
```

This function also works for the string in the opening post, except you'll get question marks in the Immediate window. To solve that, which I didn't test, you should set the locale of your system:
[Displaying Japanese text in the Immediate Window of Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219899/displaying-japanese-text-in-the-immediate-window-of-excel-vba)

For your convenience:

```
??ta????sµ?? pa???sµ??? ep?p?d?? st?? ?at??t?s
```

The Immediate window converts the Greek characters to ANSI and can't display them, at least, in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Paste it into a file and save it as a HTML file, then open it in a browser.

I got some weird font like Greek or Arabic when I tried is I'm sure it'll make more sense to you than it does to me:

Ανταγωνισμός παγκοσμίου επιπέδου στην κατάρτισ (Greek)

Comment: You are right, this is Greek language and this should be my final output. I tried the code provided by David below, and this does what I asked - it decodes HTML encoded text. However, now I realized that I need something else. I need a VB code which will decode this language characters into proper text.