# Displaying Japanese text in the Immediate Window of Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2010, I have a worksheet containing Japanese text. There is no problem editing, or displaying this. When I grab the value of a cell containing Japanese and use Debug.Print to display it in the Immediate Window it appears as ???? This would be a familiar issue if I was dealing with a browser. I would just make sure everything was in UTF-8 encoding. I have Japanese installed on my English Windows and that's all working fine. In Excel I tried to set the default language to Japanese. I changed the editor font to Arial Unicode but so far I still get question marks. I contacted Microsoft. I was passed from one person to another, but they couldn't help. They offered to pass me to a Technical support person who would charge me 500 US dollars!

How can I debug Japanese values in an English version of Excel using the Immediate Window?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/537645/can-i-get-vba-error-messages-in-english-language

Comment: I've already set the editing language to Japanese. The problem is the proofing tools are not installed and when I got to MS to buy the Japanese Language Pack, they only have the version for 2013. 2010 is no longer available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VBA development environment depends on the Windows "system locale" setting to tell it what character set to use. I got it to work using

- Windows Vista (English)
- Excel 2010 (English)

by going into the "Regional and Language Options" section of the Windows Control Panel and setting the system locale to "Japanese (Japan)"

[image: jpLocale.png]

After my system rebooted I could see Japanese characters in the VBA Immediate Window:

[image: jpVBA.png]

Comment: Thanks Gord. You have just saved me $500! I got through 7 operators at their technical answer centre and none of them could get past the idea of "macro" so thought it was a highly technical question. Silly me! I should have thought of changing the non-unicode program setting. I just assume the most popular office in the world was written by people from the 21st century!

Comment: Almost enough to get that scooter.