# Add support to column and sheet names which are in Japanese

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some logic to autogenerate string based on column Name and sheetName in VBA. It was working fine for english language.
Now, I need to do the same work for Japanese template as well as. In VBA editor, I am getting
Japanese sheetName/columnName as "-----------".
But it works if I change the language of my system from English to Japanese.

Is there any way to make Japanese template work in English OS as well?
[image]

Comment: In my Excel, I simply find a Japanese word at cell A1, and then run a code "activesheet.name = cells(1,1)", the worksheet can change to a Japanese word. Would you provide your code and screen capture to the result you get?

Comment: @Victor19 I've edited my question to add the screenshot. Please check.

Comment: What I know is the same as the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219899/displaying-japanese-text-in-the-immediate-window-of-excel-vba

Comment: Nevertheless, on my computer VBA seems to work normally even it is Japanese. The only coding problem is the word cannot be displayed in msgbox properly. I doubt whether you really need to display Japanese in VBA editor for your original purpose - "Autogenerate String"

Comment: I referred this link and after switching the language to Japanese of my system, I was able to copy paste Japanese text in VBA editor. And it was working fine as well as. 
But I need Japanese template to work in English OS also.
Yeah, I don't need MsgBox. I'm performing some actions based on column and sheet name combination. But I'm getting sheet and column Name as "----" as shown in screenshot.

Comment: Then, there should not be having problems even the excel contains Japanese words. What actual problem do you encounter if you just continue to use the same code for Japanese? From your screen, the excel can display the sheet name properly, it is just the VBA editor shown the "_" character.

Comment: Yeah right. I can see Japanese text in excel file but Macros are not working because Japanese text are read as "----".

Comment: Can you provide the code which is not working? Without the code, I cannot answer the problem

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm creating a sample for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223328/discussion-between-dipti-and-victor19).

Comment: Thank you @Victor, I tried the way you suggested i.t. adding all Japanese text in a separate sheet and compare the sheet/column names from that sheet. It worked for me.