# Userform not displaying Japanese Characters

Tags: excel, vba

Userform not displaying Japanese Characters

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lastrow1 As Variant
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim lastrow2 As Variant
    Dim j As Variant
    Dim X As Variant
    Range("Table35[ID]").Select ** Selection of data is in second sheet**
        On Error Resume Next
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B7"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            
    lastrow1 = Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To lastrow1
    On Error Resume Next
    UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 8).Value & "Class", Text:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 8).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add relative:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 8).Value & "Class", relationship:=tvwChild, Key:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 8).Value & Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 6).Value & "Sub-class", Text:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 6).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add relative:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 8).Value & Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 6).Value & "Sub-class", relationship:=tvwChild, Key:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 6).Value & Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 4).Value & "FS-Line", Text:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 4).Value
    UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add relative:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 6).Value & Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 4).Value & "FS-Line", relationship:=tvwChild, Key:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 1).Value & "Note Line", Text:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 1).Value
    UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add relative:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 1).Value & "Note Line", relationship:=tvwChild, Key:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 1).Value & "Note Line", Text:=Worksheets("Global Mapping").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i
    lastrow2 = Worksheets("Template").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 6 To lastrow2
    If Worksheets("Template").Cells(j, 4).Value <> "" Then
    UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add relative:=Worksheets("Template").Cells(j, 5).Value & "Note Line", relationship:=tvwChild, Key:=Worksheets("Template").Cells(j, 5).Value & _
    Worksheets("Template").Cells(j, 2).Value & _
        "[" & Worksheets("Template").Cells(j, 3).Value & "]" & "Detailed", Text:=Worksheets("Template").Cells(j, 2).Value & _
        "[" & Worksheets("Template").Cells(j, 3).Value & "]"
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Else
        UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem Worksheets("Template").Cells(j, 2).Value & _
        "[" & Worksheets("Template").Cells(j, 3).Value & "]"
    End If
    Next j
    UserForm1.TreeView1.HideSelection = False
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.List = Array("Class", "Sub-class", "FS-Line", "Note line", "Detailed")
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = "Class"
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = "Type to search ..."
    For X = 1 To UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Count
        If InStr(UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes(X).Key, "Note Line") Then
         UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes(X).BackColor = &HC0C0C0
        End If
    Next X
    End Sub
    'Unmap button
    Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedLeft_Click()
        Dim iCtr As Long
            On Error GoTo errorhandler
      If UserForm1.BTN_MoveSelectedLeft.Value = True Then
            If UserForm1.TreeView1.SelectedItem.Text <> "" Then
            If InStr(UserForm1.TreeView1.SelectedItem.Key, "Detailed") > 0 Then
               UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem UserForm1.TreeView1.SelectedItem.Text
               UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Remove (TreeView1.SelectedItem.Index)
            '   UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes(TreeView.SelectedItem.Index).Parent.Selected = True
                
    'Run "SortListBox", ListBox1, 0, 1, 1
            End If
            End If
            BTN_MoveSelectedLeft = False
        End If
        'BTN_MoveSelectedLeft.Value = False
        Exit Sub
    errorhandler:    *** error handling part**
    BTN_MoveSelectedLeft.Value = False
    Exit Sub
        
    End Sub
```

code is working but the problem is mentioned below

**The output shows on the right-hand side, when I move it to the left-hand side it shows Japanese but on the right side, it is not showing up. Please help**

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Arial Unicode font - it include Japanese characters and many others. Unicode font is a part of MS Office. It is not installed by default, but you may easily install it via Control Panel.

here [Displaying Japanese text in the Immediate Window of Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219899/displaying-japanese-text-in-the-immediate-window-of-excel-vba)

Comment: It is not working even after that, the problem here is we created a tree and on right hand side it is displaying some different text, when we move it to left hand side it is showing Japanese text

Comment: Can anyone please help???

Comment: Can anyone help ??pleaseeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Can any one help me ???????????