# How to resolve incorrect characters in the Immediate window of the Debug.Print function?

Tags: excel, vba

I am testing some functions in VBA, to work with files, and display the results by the Immediate window. But I have problems with character encoding, and some characters are displayed incorrectly.

I made this piece of code in Excel VBA:

```
Sub abrirArchivo()
    Dim nombreArchivo As String
    nombreArchivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Archivo Txt, *.txt", _
    Title:="Seleccione un archivo para abrir", MultiSelect:=False)
    Debug.Print "El archivo es: " & nombreArchivo
    'abrirArchivo = nombreArchivo
End Sub
```

This code is associated to a button, when I press the button and select the file "01 - M**ó**dulo 1.txt", the result shown in the Immediate Window is:
El archivo es: E:\Apuntes\UNSJ\Abogacia\Ingreso 2023\Docs\01 - M**Ã³**dulo 1.txt

The solution for this question:
[Displaying Japanese text in the Immediate Window of Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219899/displaying-japanese-text-in-the-immediate-window-of-excel-vba)

It does not work, I have this set up:

[image]

How can I work with the correct caracter in that window?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. VBE's Immediate window doesn't support these characters. The message box will also fail. If you need the correct characters, display them e.g. in Excel (e.g. in a cell or a user form) or in a text file instead, which probably is the final goal anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Although standard message boxes do not support Unicode, formatted message boxes can display Unicode character sets.

```
 Public Function FormattedMsgBox(Prompt As String, Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, _
      Optional title As String = vbNullString, Optional HelpFile As Variant, Optional Context As Variant)       As VbMsgBoxResult

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

'Originally from http://www.trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet015.asp (now defunct)

       FormattedMsgBox = Eval("MsgBox(""" & Prompt & """, " & Buttons & ", """ & title & """)")

Exit_Handler:
   Exit Function

Err_Handler:
   MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " in FormattedMsgBox procedure : " & vbCrLf & "   - " & Err.Description
   Resume Exit_Handler

End Function
```

The image below shows an example of a bilingual message box in Japanese and English

[image: example message box]

For additional info/screenshots see [FormattedMsgBox](https://www.isladogs.co.uk/formatted-message-box/)